# Fail to install twitter bootstrap node.js dependencies (on Ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, ubuntu-14.04

I've downloaded Bootstrap 3.1.1 source files from the [official website](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and I am getting errors when attempting to run `npm install` in the `bootstrap/` directory when following the [bootstrap setup directions](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#compiling-css-and-javascript) from the site.

I'm on a Ubuntu 14.04 platform with `npm 1.3.10` installed from distribution repositories, and could successfully run `npm install -g grunt-cli` without a problem.

When I try to `sudo npm install` from the bootstrap directory, however, I see a long string of successful GET messages, which then terminate with this error:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/proto-list

> phantomjs@1.9.7-4 install /home/cboettig/Documents/code/thirdparty/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've consulted the `README.Debian` mentioned in the warning, which only seems to say that Debian platforms need to call `nodejs` instead of `node` to avoid namespace collisions. I'm unsure how to verify if that is a problem.

I found the error message, `weird error 1` to be not particularly helpful either.

How do install this project cleanly without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make nodejs
```

to install node.js from repository.

Answer (score -1):

install nodejs-legacy, this fix the error